# How to inject CSS (assets) to WebView(from live url)

Tags: android, css, webview, code-injection

working on android here,

Wondering if there is a way to inject an styles.css (from assets folder) to a WebView (from an *.html without an internal copy)

for example:

www.google.com (loaded on WebView) (no internal copy on assets folder)

styles.css (located on assets folder)

Comment: someone should answer this :(